# PHP FFMPEG - Convert .mov to .mp4 (H264)

Tags: php, ffmpeg, backend, ffmpeg-php

I've recently installed the PHP-FFMpeg lib on a server and used the following tutorial: 
https://github.com/PHP-FFMpeg/PHP-FFMpeg

I managed to convert a .mov video (uploaded through a mobile device) to webm and ogg but when encoding to mp4 I always get an "Encoding Failed" message from the error object (in a try catch).

This is the code I'm using after instantiating FFMPEG

```
    $video->filters()->resize(new FFMpeg\Coordinate\Dimension(756, 461), $mode = RESIZEMODE_SCALE_WIDTH)->synchronize();

$video->frame(FFMpeg\Coordinate\TimeCode::fromSeconds(10))->save('sites/default/files/videos/thumbnails/'.$filename.'.jpg');

$video->save(new FFMpeg\Format\Video\Ogg(), 'sites/default/files/videos/'.$filename.'.ogg')
      ->save(new FFMpeg\Format\Video\X264(), 'sites/default/files/videos/'.$filename.'.mp4')
      ->save(new FFMpeg\Format\Video\WebM(), 'sites/default/files/videos/'.$filename.'.webm');
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: The github page says you need FFMpeg and FFProbe installed and in your system path (otherwise explicitly define the path). Have you made sure you've done this?

Comment: Yes! Everything is up and running from this side. By the way I managed to convert the video to MP4 through this method: 

exec("ffmpeg -i sites/default/files/videos/originals/video.mov -vcodec copy -acodec copy sites/default/files/videos/video.mp4");

Although it would be great to make it work with the library. Thanks for your reply!

Comment: I'm afraid I don't know enough about the library to help you, but if you do it with exec() then make sure you absolutely sanitize anything that comes from user input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case anyone comes upon this and needs to convert MOV to MP4 using FFMpeg, the correct method is:

```
  $ffmpeg = FFMpeg\FFMpeg::create();

  $video = $ffmpeg->open('path/to/movie.mov');
  $format = new FFMpeg\Format\Video\X264();
  $format->setAudioCodec("libmp3lame");

 $video
     ->save($format, 'path/to/movie.mp4');
```

Answer found [here](https://github.com/PHP-FFMpeg/PHP-FFMpeg/issues/310)

Comment: Gathering from the linked answer, the point is that you have to set a compatible audio codec in addition to the video codec. (I'm not sure though why it breaks if one tries to set the codec like this `$format = new FFMpeg\Format\Video\X264('libmp3lame', 'libx264');`)